# Refreshing object on separate form

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have an application that shows data from a MySQL table. Basically, my application consists of two forms: the main form, and a form for adding stuff to the database.

The main form shows all the entries in the database and relevant information. When the user wants to add a new entry to the database, a secondary form is opened that prompts for information. Once the information is filled out, the user presses a Submit button and the form closes. My problem is that when the secondary form closes, the `listBox` in the main form doesn’t update to reflect the newly-added entry.

Here is the code that is executed when the user submits the secondary form:

> ```
>     private void closeWindow()
>     {
>         mainForm parent = new mainForm();
>         parent.listParts.Refresh();
>         this.Close();
>     }
> ```

Is there a reason when I call the `listBox` to be refreshed, it doesn’t show my newly-added information? Perhaps I am calling something in the wrong order? Or does the `Refresh()` method not even work like that?

Any help would be appreciated! Alternatively, if you know of a better way to do this, I’d love to hear it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're refreshing the *wrong form*:

```
private void closeWindow()
{
    mainForm parent = new mainForm();
    parent.listParts.Refresh();
    this.Close();
}
```

Since you use:  `new mainForm()`, you're allocating a completely separate instance of the "mainForm", and refreshing it's content.  This will not effect the existing, opened form.

I would recommend passing a reference to the `mainForm` to the constructor of the secondary form.  It then would know *which instance of mainForm* it needs to use to call `Refresh()`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Do you know of a way to call the existing form?

Comment: @AndrewDeForest Pass an instance of that form when you open it.  When you create the secondary form, pass "this" (the main form that cretaed it) to that form, and store it there.  That way, you'll have the right reference the entire time.

Comment: Reed's suggestion to pass an instance is a good naive way to solve the problem, but it's not great design.  It tightly couples the two forms.  I'd suggest that's a good way to start, but you should move to a more event based approach where possible.

Comment: @Servy Yes - very true.  Using events or some form of abstraction is typically a much better design.  At a minimum, move the refreshing to some public contract on the form instead of working with the controls directly... ;)

Comment: @Reed Copsey Could you possibly help me out with passing the `mainForm` reference to the secondary form? I assume I would overload the secondary form with the `mainForm`, but it says I can't do that, as it is a type, not a variable. Am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: @AndrewDeForest in the secondary form, wher eyou have: `public SecondaryForm() { InitializeComponent(); }`, change it to: `private mainForm formToRefresh;   public SecondaryForm(mainForm main) { InitializeComponent(); formToRefresh = main; }`.  Later, you would then do `formToRefresh....Refresh();`

Comment: @Reed Copsey Thanks! I really do appreciate the help! This is starting to become much clearer to me. One more thing, however…how do I pass the instance of the `mainForm` to the `secondaryForm`? Or basically, how should I use `mainForm` as a variable?

Comment: @AndrewDeForest If you're creating the secondary form *from* an event in mainForm, just pass "this":  `secondaryForm newForm = new secondaryForm(this);`

Comment: @Reed Copsey Thanks for everything! Working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Reed has [given an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047149/1159478) with why what you did din't work, here's one possible solution for how to actually fix it:

in some event handler for MainForm:

```
var otherForm = new SomeOtherForm();
otherForm.Closed += (sender, args) =>
{
  //update the listbox in MainForm here
};
```

If you need information from the second form to update the listbox, then make a public property in `SomeOtherForm` that exposes the data needed by `MainForm`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reload the data again. fetch it again set the datasource

Have a Parent Property to your child form which is of type of your First form.

some thing like this.

**Your Parent form**

```
public partial class KitTypes : Form
{

 public void ReloadData()
 {
   // Get the data and Set as datasource of control
 }

}
```

**And the Child form**

```
public partial class Kit : Form
{
    private int _KitId=0;
    private KitTypes _parentForm = null;


 public Kit(KitTypes parentForm)
 {
   _parentForm =parentForm;
 }
}
```

And from your First form, when you create an object of this, pass the parent form as the parameter

```
  Kit objChild=new kit(this);
  objChild.Show();
```

Now in your child, form you can call the public method of parent form like this

```
this._parentForm.ReloadData();
```

Comment: The underlying problem, as mentioned by reed, is that he's using the wrong instance of the form.